# Export Basic 3D Model (.OBJ/..MTL) with Only Modified Base Color

Tags: export

Blender Newbie Help Request!
I am using Blender v3.5.1 ...
I exported a simple primitive mesh (example: icosphere)
as 3d model legacy format wavefront .obj w/.mtl file
with edited base color.
Exported model has default (gray) color.
Saving file first resulted in no change.

I require wavefront .obj w/.mtl file export.
Not using texture/image file.
Just basic export must include .obj file w/.mtl
file modified color.
Not alternate file format.

Please offer a solution.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the problem is not in the target software? Did you try to import it back to Blender?

Answer (score 0):

A recent update to Windows 11 on my computer resolved the issue.
Export of Legacy Wavefront OBJ/MTL now successful.